# Dynamically change theme of shinymaterial

Tags: r, shiny, materialize

Is there a way to dynamically change the theme used in a `shinymaterial` page?

In comparison, this is possible with `shinydashboard`, `shinydashboardPlus`,

As a reminder, Eric Rayanderson explains [here](https://ericrayanderson.github.io/shinymaterial/) how to set up colors in `material_page()` but I don't see any `update_material_page()`:

```
material_page(
  title = "Basic Page", 
  primary_theme_color = "blue", 
  secondary_theme_color = "red",
  material_row(
    material_column(
      width = 12,
      material_button("button", "Button"),
      material_switch("switch", "", "off", "on"),
      material_radio_button("radio", "", c("A", "B", "C"))
    )
  )
)
```

Example of desired output: in package bs4Dash there is a top right button which allows for instance switching between light and dark mod:

```
library(shiny);library(bs4Dash)
shinyApp(ui = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(), dashboardSidebar(), dashboardBody(), title = "switch theme via top right btn"),
 server = function(input, output) { })
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no `update_material_page()`, a possible workaround using only R is to render new ui every time the switch input is pressed. To keep the inputs status when the colors are changed, their values can be saved inside a `reactiveValues` and then insert them back again once the ui with different colors finished rendering.

In this code a new ui get's rendered and all the inputs go back to their default value.

```
#Dynamically change theme of shinymaterial

library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('material_ui')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    clrs <- reactiveValues()
    clrs$primary <- 'blue'
    clrs$secondary <- 'red'
    clrs$switch_status <- FALSE
    

    
    output$material_ui <- renderUI({
        
        print(clrs$switch_status)
        
        material_page(
            title = "Basic Page", 
            primary_theme_color = clrs$primary, 
            secondary_theme_color = clrs$secondary,
            material_row(
                material_column(
                    width = 12,
                    material_button("button", "Button"),
                    checkboxInput("switch", "Dark mode:",value = clrs$switch_status),
                    material_radio_button("radio", "", c("A", "B", "C"))
                )
            )
        )
        
    })
    
    
    
    observeEvent(input$switch, {
        
        if (input$switch) {
            
            clrs$primary <- 'black'
            clrs$secondary <- 'grey'
            clrs$switch_status <- TRUE
            

        } else {
            
            clrs$primary <- 'blue'
            clrs$secondary <- 'red'
            clrs$switch_status <- FALSE
            

        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a possible workaround more easier (relatively to a heavy app which would have a lot of inputs) in non-R solution? 
Otherwise, maybe using the genuine bookmark functionnality would work.

Comment: By the way checking the switch in your app code does not change the colors from my side.

Comment: does the code works from your side? It is not the case from mine. What is your session info please?